# A question about infinite sequence of subspaces.

Tags: linear-algebra

I am tasked to find an example of a Vector space $V$ and an infinite sequence of subspaces of $\{ S_i \}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ such that $$S_1 \subset S_2 \subset \cdots$$
with each subset being proper.

My first intuition is to consider the space $P^n$, the vector space of polynomials with real coefficients. If we let $S_i = P^i$ we clearly have that $$S_1 \subset S_2 \subset \cdots$$

My question is what would my $V$ be? Would it be $P^{\infty}$? What would $P^{\infty}$ look like?

If there is a better example, please let me know.

Comment: The vector space of all real sequences, $\Bbb R^{\Bbb N}$ and the subspaces as $\Bbb R,\Bbb R^2,\Bbb R^3,...$

Comment: Oh wow... I don't know why I did not think of that immediately

Comment: @Emma The vector space of **all** polynomials (as opposed to polynomials with degree at most $n$) would be a suitable $V$.

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you. Is there a standard notation for the vector space of all polynomials?

Comment: Also, question, how do com to terms with the "infinite sequence"  condition since by definition, shouldn't polynomials have finite degrees?